# Dacor W305 electric oven broiler element will not heat in preheat mode only

Tags: repair

My Dacor W305 electric oven top broiler element will not heat in the preheat mode.  The broiler element works fine when turned to broil.  All other functions work as normal.  Brand new Control board (not used or refurbished) was replaced 18 months ago and broiler preheat function was working fine at that time.  Any ideas on the culprit to solving this problem?

Comment: Was it the same problem for replacing the old board of a different problem?  Something in the pre-heat circuit is not working/connecting, but if a button, a wire or another component is hard to tell without testing.

Comment: Old board was replaced only because could no longer read the LED display.  Could problem be in selectors switch contacts or maybe the broiler relay board?

Comment: Can be any part of the pre heat circuit.  See if you have or can find a wiring diagram online.  You are with/close 240v and 30/40 amps so be very careful if working with the power on.  Most tests should be able to be done with power off/unplugged.

Comment: How are you determining the broiler element is not working? My info indicates it operates at 1/4 power (so likely supplied with 120V only) during preheat. This may not cause element to glow. This also implies far more current on the "neutral" wiring than is standard for ovens/cooktops, so something may have gone awry with that part of the supply wiring.

Comment: Bottom bake element glows on preheat so I assumed that the broiler element would also glow on preheat to heat the oven more quickly.  My research was peeked about this because my wife was complaining that the preheat was taking much longer than normal to heat the oven to the desired temperature.  1/4 power could be possible but that is news to me.  I will pursue this further to see if that is correct.

Comment: OKAY KREEMOWEET YOU ARE ABSOLUTELY CORRECT!  Just tried to preheat the oven and broiler element would not glow but it was hot.  So, the 1/4 power scenario is correct.  Thank you for clarifying this for me so I will not pursue this issue any further.  My wife must have been totally mistaken about the slower heat up time (probably just too anxious to wait any longer)!